# Eliminar datos con ajax, php y mvc

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mvc

Tengo un proyecto en php con el diseño MVC sin framework, deseo eliminar los registros almacenados a travez de un ajax pero no le llega el valor del id al controlador.

Este es el codigo de la vista, un boton para eliminar con al siguiente configuracion

```
 <button class="eliminarr" onclick="eliminar(<?php echo $value->id ?>)">ELIMINAR</button>
```

y aca esta la funcion para eliminar

```
function eliminar(id){
      var id = id;
      var el =confirm('Desea eliminar la Actividad con ID = '+id+' ?')
      if (el == true){
        $.ajax({
          url : "<?php echo SERVERURL?>controladores/actividadControlador.php/eliminarActividad",
          data : {id},
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'post',
          success:function( eliminado ){
            alert(eliminado)
          }
        });
      }else{
        alert('Registro con ID = '+id+' No Eliminado')
      }
    }
```

y este es el encavezado de mi controlador

```
 <?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/../modelos/actividadModelo.php";

class actividadControlador extends actividadModelo{
    public function viewInsert(){
        require './vistas/contenido/insertActividad-view.php';
    }

public function eliminarActividad($identificador){

        $lenguaje = 'json';
        $eliminado = $this->eliminarAct($identificador);

        header("location: administracionAct");
        //echo json_encode($eliminado);

    }
}
```

el problema es que no le esta llegando el id a el controlador, yo creo que es por la forma en que estoy declarando la url, pero no tengo idea de como debe de ser cuando esta configurado con el modelo MVC sin framework

Comment: Puedes intentar agregar el `id` a la `url` de envío `url : "<?php echo SERVERURL?>controladores/actividadControlador.php/eliminarActividad/" + id,`

Comment: si la mando por alli no la recibe por $_GET? por que en el metodo necesito mandarla por $_POST, y de igual forma no obtengo el valor del id para poder enviarlo al controlador

Comment: Puedes intentar enviar el id así `data: { id: id },`  sin `dataType: 'json',` y recibirlo en el controlador como `$id = $_POST['id'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que antes de enviar el ID te asegures que esta llegando a la función JS, ademas de eso tambien trata de poner en comillas simples los valores php que vayan junto con js y obvio el punto y coma(almenos yo tuve problemas sin las comillas):

```
<button class="eliminarr" onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $value->id; ?>')">ELIMINAR</button>
```

En tu función puedes asegurarte que llegue correctamente:

```
function eliminar(id){
   alert(id);
}
```

Adicional, puede ser que no este llegando correctamente el url, asi que guardalo en una variable:

```
function eliminar(id){
      var id = id;
      var urlmvc = '<?php echo SERVERURL; ?>';
      var el =confirm('Desea eliminar la Actividad con ID = '+id+' ?');
      if (el == true){
        $.ajax({
          url : urlmvc+"controladores/actividadControlador.php/eliminarActividad",
          .
          .
```

Por ultimo enviar un dato al controlador para conocer que vas a eliminar y alli llamas a la funcion php de eliminar.

```
$.ajax({
  url : urlmvc+"controladores/actividadControlador.php?eliminar=1",
  .
  .
```

Y en tu controlador algo asi:

```
if(isset($_GET['eliminar']) $$ $_GET['eliminar']!=null){
   $cual_elimino=$_GET['eliminar'];
   if($cual_elimino==1){
      $identificador=$_POST['id'];
      eliminarActividad($identificador);
   }
}
```

Si no deseas hacer ese proceso por get, puedes crear una variable y enviar un parametro para eliminar y el ID.

```
var parametros = { 
 "eliminar" : 1,
 "id" : id
}
```

y en el ajax:

```
data : parametros,
```

y en tu controlador haces un POST en vez de un GET.